# Xamarin.ios - resx reference in xaml file not working

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, resx

I've a AppResources.resx file where I store all strings that I use across my app. My Xamarin project contains two solutions one for Android and another for iOS. The Android app is working perfectly. But the iOS app is throwing Xaml errors that say something like "Cannot found static member AppResources".

Here's my xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HalliganTL;assembly=HalliganTL"
             x:Class="HalliganTL.View.LoginPage">
  <Grid Style="{StaticResource backgroundColor}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Entry x:Name="entryEmail"
           Placeholder="{x:Static local:AppResources.login_page_email_placeholder}" Text="{Binding Username}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Entry x:Name="entryPassword"
           Placeholder="{x:Static local:AppResources.login_page_password_placeholder}"
           Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="true" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsRunning="False" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.login_page_login_button_text}"
            Style="{StaticResource redButton}" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.login_page_forgot_password_button_text}"
           Style="{StaticResource blueButton}" Clicked="OnForgotPasswordClicked" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>


  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Any tip about what can be causing this error?

**UPDATE**

I removed all AppResources.resx references in the XAML file, and yet It throws an error telling me that the "OnLoginButtonClicked" method doesn't exist in the .cs code. But It clearly does!

Here's my .cs code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using HalliganTL.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using XLabs.Ioc;

namespace HalliganTL.View
{
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            Title = AppResources.login_page_title;
            BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
        }

        async void OnForgotPasswordClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ForgotPasswordPage());
        }

        async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Validates email
            if (!HalliganUtils.IsValidEmail(entryEmail.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert(AppResources.error_title, 
                    AppResources.login_page_email_validation_error, 
                    AppResources.accept_button_text);
                return;
            }
            //Validates password
            if (!HalliganUtils.IsValidPassword(entryPassword.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert(AppResources.error_title,
                    AppResources.login_page_password_validation_error,
                    AppResources.accept_button_text);
                return;
            }
            HalliganCredential credentials = new HalliganCredential
            {
                Email = entryEmail.Text,
                Password = entryPassword.Text
            };

            await App.RestClient.GetUserAuthAsync(credentials)
                .OnSuccess((result) =>
                {
                    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPage(), this);
                    Navigation.PopAsync();
                })
                .OnRequestStarted(() =>
                {
                    activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
                    entryEmail.IsEnabled = false;
                    entryPassword.IsEnabled = false;
                })
                .OnRequestCompleted(() =>
                {
                    activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                    entryEmail.IsEnabled = true;
                    entryPassword.IsEnabled = true;
                })
                .OnHttpError((exception) =>
                {
                    DisplayAlert(AppResources.error_title, 
                        AppResources.login_page_login_failed_message, 
                        AppResources.accept_button_text);
                })
                .OnUnknownError((exception) =>
                {
                    DisplayAlert(AppResources.error_title,
                        AppResources.unknown_error,
                        AppResources.accept_button_text);
                })
                .Start();
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried changing the method signatures but didn't work. What I tried:

`public async void OnForgotPasswordClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)`

and

`public void OnForgotPasswordClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: Looks like the `OnLoginButtonClicked` and `OnForgotPasswordClicked` methods are private.

Comment: But why does It works on Android and not in iOS?

Comment: I was commenting to your update, about the method not being found from XAML, not to the original question.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Do you get this error in runtime. If so then you must be using `link all assemblies` in Android and `link sdk assemblies` in ios.

Comment: @AkashAmin Yes I'm getting the error at Runtime. I actually tried with every link option, I tried with "Link only SDK", "Don't Link" and "Link all assemblies" in iOS. I didn't touch anything in the Android project about the linking behaviour.

Comment: When you change the linking try to remove the application from the simulator or phone and run again.